# Eclipse RCP Window / Dialog Registry

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Is there any standard mechanism in RCP or JFace to register a window or dialog so that if the user calls a handler which brings up a dialog two times, and the second time the selection hasn't changed, instead of bringing up a new dialog, the dialog that was previously opened becomes focused?

Answer (score 0):

JFace dialogs are destroyed when they are closed so you can't really save them.

You can save and restore values in dialogs using something like the JFace `DialogSettings` class.

Comment: Yes, but let's say the window is not closed. It is merely redundant. A new window should not opened, the first opened window should merely be refocused.